# problem related to build APK file in FLUTTER regarding the kotlin version and gradle versions

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

there is a big problem realted to kotlin and gradle versions in flutter so i am not able to build  the apk file   and in the terminal there the output is -----

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2,975ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

pls resolve this issues to build the apk file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project `android> build_gradle` and add the following kotlin-gradle-plugin.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```